# Admob plugin fail when enable MonacaPushNotifcations

Tags: cordova, plugins, admob, google-play-services, monaca

I have tried to build an .apk with admob plugin(admob.com.cranberrygame.cordova.plugin.ad.admob) in monaca but fail.
When i remove the pushnotification plugin , that can build successfully. The error code show that "Found 2 versions of google-play-services.jar in the dependency list". These any ways to solve the problems?

Thank You Very Much . Thank You Very Much

[dependency] Found 2 versions of google-play-services.jar in the dependency list,
[dependency] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[dependency] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[dependency] Versions found are: